# Travel questions for non US citizens residing in the U.S

Tags: visas, uk, applications, us-residents

While filling the application for a UK visa, they ask if we have traveled in certain countries which includes the US. Since I am a non US citizen living in the US should I give details of my visits to the US every time?

Answer (score 1):

If the question is to list all countries visited prior to this visit to the UK, then you should include the US.

If they ask you to give details of each stay then yes you have to include arrival and departure dates. If you arrived once and never left the US then you may be able to fill the `From` field and leave the `To` field as `current`.